# Getting SQL state: 25P02 while trying to update a table with data from another

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am using a PostgreSQL DB. I have two tables, namely `company` and `bl_location`. I have a field `location_id` in both tables. Now I am trying to copy the value of `location_id` from `bl_location` to `company`. The primary key of `company` is `company_id` and it is stored in `bl_location` too. I am trying the following query:

```
UPDATE company 
    SET location_id = bl_location.location_id 
from bl_location  
where company.company_id = bl_location.company_id;
```

using the syntax I found online:

```
update table1
set col1 = . . .
from table2
where table1.id = table2.table1_id
```

But I am getting the following in the console of the `pgAdmin` tool:

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

********** Error **********

ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
SQL state: 25P02
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my query.

Comment: There must be a different error before that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that was a typo. I have corrected it in the question, also there is no other error before that

Comment: "current transaction is aborted" is **always** the result of a previous error. Maybe you don't log that error properly, but that message never shows up on its own.

Answer (score 4):

RCA : This issue happens when last transitions ended up with error and not rolled back

FIX : psql > ROLLBACK

if you're using PGAdmin click on rollback & enable auto rollback option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are aware of it or not, your statement is running inside an explicit transaction, and one of the preceeding statements is the same transaction must have caused an error.

To debug this, consider setting `log_statement = 'all'` so that all statments get logged. By tracing all statements from the same backend PID you will be able to identify the culprit.